# What are possible other "point sources" in the Fermi-LAT paper?

Tags: experimental-physics, astrophysics, astronomy, gamma-rays

This [*Fermi-LAT* Collaboration paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02938v1) (from 2015) looks at the Galactic centre and fits the $\gamma$-ray data with smooth interstellar medium emission, and with "point sources". It mentions that some of them overlap with known supernova remnants, some with pulsars, and some could be attributed to mis-identified interstellar emission.

Are there any other possible interpretations for these point sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, in general they could be any gamma-ray emitting point sources: general (non-known-pulsar) neutron stars, or stellar mass black holes, or even background AGN.  I'm not sure what they have in mind for 'interstellar emission' but that might also include a hydrodynamic shock in the interstellar medium here or there.